# ASP.NET MVC5 Passing an ID and a redirect to another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Trying to redirect to another controller action (Course) while passing in the selected ID from a different controller which shows the COurses via a viewmodel

What is the correct syntax to display EDIT to the user, redirect to the Courses Controller, select the EDIT action on the Courses Controller and pass in the selected id

I've tried

```
 @Html.ActionLink({"Edit", Action="Edit", area = "Courses", courseID = item.CourseID})
```

but the syntax is wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Create", new { courseID = item.CourseID })

Comment: You noted your controller is `CoursesController` but you have specified `area = "Courses"` Do you also have areas in your app?

Comment: Thanks all, Hi Stephen, No I don't have areas in the application. I was trying that after doing some research. Half baked thought was that areas were a proxy for redirecting to another controller but I'm guessing that's not correct??

Comment: @JohnO'Grady, See my comment to Ala's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Courses", new { courseID = item.CourseID},null)
```

will redirect you to: `localhost:56802/Courses/Edit?courseID=1`

In order to redirect you to `localhost:56802/Courses%20/Edit/2`:

**Method 1:**

If you are using the default route:

```
                    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

use the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Courses", new { id = item.CourseID},null)
```

**Method 2:**
Use the following route:

```
                        routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        url: "{controller}/{action}/{courseID}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", courseID = UrlParameter.Optional });

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Courses", new { courseID = item.CourseID},null)
```

Comment: You have added the `courseId` as a html attribute, not a route value

Comment: thanks folks- appreciate you taking the time to respond. That updated version is redirecting to http://localhost:56802/Colleges/Edit?Length=8 where 8 is the ID number. Colleges is the Controller which I am trying to redirect (on selecting a course in the CourseIndexView which allows the user to select a college and then on the same Index page (via View Model) view specific courses. What I'm trying to achieve is that the Edit Action button on one of those courses redirects to   http://localhost:56802/Courses/Edit/2.

Comment: Still not correct, it needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Courses ", new { courseID = item.CourseID }, null)`

Comment: thanks so much Stephen. Your answer almost gets me there. It redirects to the right Controller but the URL is still slightly at odds with the routing. It redirects to http://localhost:56802/Courses%20/Edit?courseID=1 but I need something like http://localhost:56802/Courses/Edit/2

Comment: Then you need to use `new { ID = item.CourseID }` (assuming your using the default route) or create a route with a parameter - `url: /Courses/Edit/{CourseID}`

Comment: Thanks Stephen- that was a great help. Final version using your advice was 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Courses", new { ID = item.CourseID }, null)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have a route for edit course, you can use Html.Routelink and just use the default routing.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "Default", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {{"controller", "courses"}, {"action", "edit"}, {"id", item.CourseID }})
```

However if you have a specific route for this like the sample route below,

```
 routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
            "Edit_course", // Route name
            "courses/edit/{courseid}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Courses",
                action = "Edit",
                courseid = UrlParameter.Optional
            },
            new string[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
        );
```

I guess you can use:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "Edit_course", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {{"controller", "courses"}, {"action", "edit"}, {"courseid", item.CourseID }})
```

This way, you can generate a url to that specific route, rather than just creating a url based on first matching route by action name.